# SSH reverse tunnel for Windows RDP

Tags: ssh, rdp, tunneling

Microsoft RDP seems to behave strangely when forwarded via ssh reverse (-R) tunnel. Some products can handle it without a problem (i.e. tunnelier) some fail (libssh2, putty).

When connected, the tunnelied connection will show login window and everything works until you enter proper user and password - then screen becomes black and disconnects after a minute. This behaviour is mentioned in several places around the internet (i.e. here: http://forums.anandtech.com/archive/index.php/t-2026629.html ), but I guess no solution was found by now (and this is quite old bug!)

Is anyone aware if there's ssh server / ssh client combination (apart from tunnelier) that works?